# Quick yanking in Vim

Tags: vim, editor, editing

I often find myself in a situation like this:

```
line i want to yank
.
.
.
[cursor position]
```

I want to yank the line and paste to `[cursor position]`.

I'm doing that with `[n]k`, `Y`, `[n]j`, `p`. That's a lot of typing ;). Before, I was using:

```
:[line number]Y
```

and then pasting, but that doesn't work with relative line numbers (`relativenumber` option).

What's the fastest way to do such yanking/pasting while relative numbers are ON?

Comment: I think of `[n]k` as **crawling**. If you crawl, you will have to crawl back, but if you **jump**, you can jump back: navigate your jump list with `Control+o` for older and `Control+i` for newer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When the number of the line to copy is known (whether it is absolute or
relative), a convenient way to duplicate that line is to use the `:copy`
command.  For example, the Ex command below copies the line which is four
lines above and pastes it below the current one.

```
:-4t.
```

Comment: this is fantastic. Just my curiosity, what does t stands for in this case ?

Comment: @nXqd:  `:t` is just a synonym for `:copy` (which also has a short form of `:co`).  Run `:help :copy` to see the corresponding section in Vim documentation.

Answer (score 8):

If the line is within sight (before or after cursor position), I normally just search for it (`?line i want`), yank, then go  ``` `` ``` (back to previous position), then `p`.

Comment: Or explicitly set a mark with `mm` and return with `'m` (`m` being my go-to temporary mark identifier).  I distrust previous position for some reason.

Comment: is there a reason you choose ? over / ?

Comment: @AndyRay previous (`?`) instead of next (`/`), that's all.

Answer (score 5):

I'll try this:

- <kbd>?yank</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>   <== type **`significant patten`** to search backward
- <kbd>yy</kbd>
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>  <== go back
- <kbd>p</kbd>

Comment: +1 I use `CTRL-O` and `CTRL-I` a lot, they're incredibly useful.

Answer (score 5):

```
 :/your desired search for the specific line/ y
```

or

```
 :N y
```

(where `N` is the specific line number) will copy the specific line (and it can be a range too). Now you hit <kbd>p</kbd> to paste it. This way you does not move the cursor.

Answer (score 4):

By the way, if I really do intend to repeat a line that I have used before anywhere in any of the currently open files, then I simply use the shortcut `^X^L` in insert mode after typing a few of the starting characters.

Let's say I want to repeat this line, which recurs a lot in my program:

```
for (int i = 0; i < numChildren; i++) {
```

Then I start by typing `for (in` and then just hit `^X^L`, and Vim completes it for me. (Actually it waits for me to accept it; if I do `^L` again, it shows me the next option.)

Look up `^X^L`, it's very handy.

```
:help ^X^L
```

PS: Posting as a separate answer, since your original question is specifically about "yanking" and this is auto-completion, technically.

Answer (score 2):

If the line is **out of sight** (addition to [Manish](https://stackoverflow.com/users/579230/manish)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9534638/520162)), I find it handy to

- split the screen by typing `:sp` and then
- search the line to be yanked
- yank the pattern in the upper part and then
- jump to the lower screen using <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>w</kbd>-<kbd>j</kbd> where the cursor is still placed (in the same column) as it was when I `:sp`lit the buffer.